# How can i add a predefined row in excel after each non empty cell in vb

Tags: excel, vba

I have a flat file export of a 1 to many field in excel.
I'm looking to update sections of the data by adding a row with predetermined values

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Male | tall |
|  |  | dark |
|  |  | handsome |
| Mary | Female | slender |
|  |  | funny |
| Karen | Female | annoying |

The value i want to append in column C:
(i'm happy to manually add this to the code)
Single

I'm trying to create a script in vb that parses column A,
Look for (all rows that are blank in column A && where the next column A is filled)
append a row with my value in column C

The end result would look like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Male | tall |
|  |  | dark |
|  |  | handsome |
|  |  | single |
| Mary | Female | slender |
|  |  | funny |
|  |  | single |
| Karen | Female | annoying |
|  |  | single |

(i'm ok to do the last one by hand if it comes to it :))

So far all i've managed to massacre is scripts that add blank lines or asterisks every blank line but to no avail

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Then edit your question and post your code. This is not a free script writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'select "c1" cell and then run this macro

Public Sub InsertSingle()

    Dim s As Range
    Set s = ActiveCell
    
    Dim firstTime As Boolean
    firstTime = True
    
    While s.Value <> ""
    
       If s.Offset(, -2).Value <> "" Then
          If Not firstTime Then
            s.EntireRow.Insert xlAbove
            s.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "single"
          Else
            firstTime = False
          End If
       
       End If
       
       Set s = s.Offset(1, 0)
    
    Wend

End Sub
```

[See the Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb03n.png)

Comment: Juan Carlos, this is your first answer here, so please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. We don't want to encourage lazy questions by writing code for people who don't show any effort of their own.

Comment: However i'm very glad you did, because this was far outside my comfort zone and i learned from your solution. Have adapted it slightly to do even more than i needed. Thank you very much!